# How can I check if my Google Analytics code is right?

Tags: google-analytics

My site is www.mensusa.com .Now I am creating a sub domain for my site that is `www.local.mensusa.com` (created in WordPress).

I added Google Analytics code in my sub domain site same as in www.mensusa.com.

Query(issue):

Can I add Google analytics code in sub domain?

How can I check if my analytics code is working properly or not?

If it's wrong, then how can I correct it?

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        _uacct = "UA-2085156-1";
        urchinTracker();
        </script>
```

Comment: have you read the developer site? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite

Comment: Check Google Analytics dashboard..

Comment: Google Analytics Debugger - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add GA to your subdomain.

To check if your tracking implementation is correct, you can do several things.

1. In the Chrome browser, you can install Google Tag Assistant, which will give you diagnostics about your tracking snippet. This applies to GA and GTM.
2. After you have installed the tracking snippet, check in your Real-Time reports to see if your own hits are being tracked.
3. In your GA account, you can check the tracking status under Tracking Info > Tracking Code. Look for Status. If it's good, then it will say "Receiving Data". You normally have to wait at least 24 hours for the status to update after your initial install.